# JQuery DataTables not displaying properly when populating table from MySql Table

Tags: php, datatables, tablesorter

The problem is all in my PHP WHILE Loop somehow, I know this for sure.  It turns off all the DataTables features when I use this PHP script inside a table.  All the sorts and pagination features are not present when I use "PHP WHILE" in conjuction with DataTables.
But if I type direct text in the "Example_Value" between TD tags it works fine.

It is pulling data from MySql Table and displaying correct value.  Somehow the PHP script is turning off all the DataTables features.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/lato" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">

<?php
$dir    = '../customer/demo/';
$company_name_array = scandir($dir);
$company_count = count($company_name_array);
$i = 1;

// Loop through array
foreach($company_name_array as $stores){
$storesdisplay[$i] = $stores;
$i=$i+1;
}

require 'dbConfig2.php';

?>

<div class="container-fluid">
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Last Contact</th>
<th>Send</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php
$company_name = $company_name_array;
$i=1;
// Loop through array
while($i <= $company_count ){
$i=$i+1;
$company_name = $storesdisplay[$i];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $company_name WHERE record_id =:record_id"); 
$stmt->bindValue(':record_id',1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

?>
<tr>
<td><a href="<?php echo $dir.$company_name ?>/index.php?company_logo=<?php echo $row['company_logo'] ?>"><?php echo str_replace("_"," ",$company_name) ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['contact'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['last_contact'] ?></td>

<td><a href="#"><button class="btn">Send</button></a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}         

?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>Company</th>
<th>Phone</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>last_contact</th>
<th>Send</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable();
} );

</script>
```

Comment: Since Datatables is Javascript, and it doesn't work, it is likely there's a javascript error. Have a look in [the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) of your browser. Any red error lines?

Comment: Console Log is Clean

Comment: Sorry, I cannot explain this problem. I cannot run your code, which makes it hard to debug it. Another thing I thought of is: An PHP error could happen when you include the PHP while loop, therefore never adding the `$('#example').DataTable();` script to your HTML output. If that isn't present datatables will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you KIKO Software for leading me down the right path.  In-fact you were correct, PHP was throwing an error.  As I was loading $company_name into array, the first file read was "..".  I corrected this problem with one simple correction.  I initialized $i = 1; , rather than $i = 0;

Comment: I have also made the correction in the original question, for anyone else that may run into this problem.  PHP has to run clean, No Errors or DataTables will not work correctly.  Thanks Again KIKO Software